# Using datasets in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

So, I am trying to figure out how to use the new input pipeline framework in TF. The toy model I am using for it tries to memorize an image by training on pixel coordinates as inputs and RGB values as labels. The code I have at the moment goes something like this

```py
W=442
H=500

image = tf.read_file('kitteh.png')
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
# normalize to 0-1 range
image = (image - tf.reduce_min(image)) / (tf.reduce_max(image) - tf.reduce_min(image))

# features and labels
coordinates = tf.constant([(x, y) for x in range(W) for y in range(H)], dtype=tf.float32)
rgb = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 3])

# dataset and input pipeline
features = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(coordinates)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(rgb)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((features, labels))

batched = data.batch(100)
iterator = batched.make_one_shot_iterator()
inputs, labels = iterator.get_next()


def net(inputs, reuse=False):
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l1', reuse=reuse)
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l2', reuse=reuse)
    l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l3', reuse=reuse)
    l4 = tf.layers.dense(l3, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l4', reuse=reuse)
    l5 = tf.layers.dense(l4, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l5', reuse=reuse)
    l6 = tf.layers.dense(l5, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l6', reuse=reuse)
    l7 = tf.layers.dense(l6, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l7', reuse=reuse)
    return tf.layers.dense(l7, 3, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name='out', reuse=reuse)

model = net(inputs)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, model)

step = tf.train.get_global_step()
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, global_step=step)

test = net(coordinates, reuse=True)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run((tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))
    orig = session.run(image)
    for i in range(50000):
        f, l = session.run([inputs, labels])
        print(f.shape, l.shape)
```

And here are the questions:

1. This code doesn't work. For whatever reason, the `batch()` function doesn't work right. When I try to print my label and input shapes, I expect to get `(100, 2)` and `(100, 3)`, but I get `(1, 221000, 2)`, `(1, 221000, 3)` and an `OutOfRangeError`. I seem to be following the "importing data" tutorial, but I do not get the expected result.
2. How do I get a full set of data from a dataset? I want to have it generate a complete picture on every Nth step, can I get all the coordinates from the dataset?
3. I have width and height of the image hard-coded, but it would be nice to get them from the decoded data. I tried to do `W = image.get_shape()[0]` but it resulted in my `parser()` function failing because W is not defined yet. Is there a solution?

Edit #1: updated the code to my latest attempt and updated the questions to reflect the latest problem I am getting.

Edit #3: it seems I made a mistake in my previous edit. The problem seems to be with `batch()` rather than `zip()`. When I print output shapes for data and batched datasets, I get the following

```py
(TensorShape([Dimension(221000), Dimension(2)]), 
 TensorShape([Dimension(221000), Dimension(3)]))
(TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(221000), Dimension(2)]), 
 TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(221000), Dimension(3)]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the first and primary issue. It seems that there is a subtle difference between `Dataset.from_tensor()` and 'Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`. Both take tensors as arguments, but the prior method treats the whole tensor as a single training sample, where the later treats the first axis as samples and the rest as data, thus splitting the tensor into samples along the first axis. Using the later function fixed the problem I had.

As for questions 2 and 3, I would still love to hear any answers, but currently there seems to be no way to do it the way I want, so I have ended up using hard-coded image dimensions and using `coordinates` constant tensor to paint a complete image.